# JQuery form validation Required failing in Chrome browser

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-validate

I'm using JQuery to validate a form. The form has two fields. One is text, the other a file. The required method is used for each field. When submit is clicked without selecting a name or file the form submits without these two values.

However, this works on desktop Firefox 56.0, on my phone's Chrome 63.0.03239.11 but not on my desktop Chrome Version 63.0.3239.108 (Official Build) (64-bit).
Also, I note that required validation works if I'm not uploading a file in a form and just using `$(form).serialize()` to capture the form text fields. Should I submit a Chrome bug report about this?

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script> var myPath = "/timelines/post_photo.php";</script>

<form id="foo">                               
    <div class="form-group">
    <!-- Child id -->
    <label for="name">Child's name:</label>
    <select multiple class="form-control" name="child" id="name">
        <option style="display:none" disabled selected value></option>
        <option value="1"> Jim Bergin </option>
        <option value="2"> Harry Potter </option>
        <option value="3"> John Carpenter </option>
        <option value="4"> Johnny Ive </option>
        <option value="5"> Steve Jobs </option>
    </select>
    </div>

    <!-- Upload Photo -->
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="photo">Upload photo:</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="photo" id="photo" />                                
    <img src="/timelines/images/loading.gif" class="img-fluid" id="loading-indicator" style="display:none" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>
 </form>
```

Validation Script

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var request;

    $("#foo").validate({
            //Our required fields
            rules: {
                    child: {
                            required: true
                    },
                    photo: {
                            required: true
                    }
            },

            submitHandler: function(form) {
                    $('#loading-indicator').show();

                    //Create variable to hold the form data
                    var fd = new FormData($(this)[0]);                        

                    //Create request function
                    request = $.ajax({
                            url: myPath,
                            type: "POST",
                            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                            data: fd,
                            processData: false,
                            contentType: false,
                            cache: false
                    });

                    request.done(function(response) {
                        // Show and fade out success message                        
                    });

                    request.fail(function (response) {
                        // Show an error message                                
                    });
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: Seems like you should be showing us the actual code as **rendered** in the DOM, not the PHP as we have no idea what it's generating.

Comment: You said, *"The required method is used for each field"* ~ not according to your code.  You only have `required` on the field named `child`... and even then we can't see the HTML so we don't know if you have a `value=""` on the first `option`.

Comment: I've edited my code to show the code rendered in the DOM for the child field and also added the required method for the second field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few issues here:

```
<select multiple class="form-control" name="child" id="name">
    <option style="display:none" disabled selected value></option>
    <option value="1"> Jim Bergin </option>
    <option value="2"> Harry Potter </option>
    <option value="3"> John Carpenter </option>
    <option value="4"> Johnny Ive </option>
    <option value="5"> Steve Jobs </option>
</select>
```

- In order to validate a `select` element, the very first `option` must contain `value=""`.  Since yours only contains `value`, it *may* be interpreted as something other than `value=""` depending on browser.
- You have `display:none`, so the validation plugin is probably not going to take this element into consideration, because by default, hidden elements are ignored.
- You have the `disabled` attribute, so the validation plugin is probably not going to take this element into consideration either.
- And finally, you have a `selected` attribute.  So if this `option` is "selected" programmatically, then the `required` rule is automatically satisfied and there is no point validating this element.

I think the four bullet points above are somewhat contradictory with each other and therefore could explain why you're seeing different results in different browsers.

Comment: thanks, all seems to be well this morning. Required fields are working. My guess is it was Chrome desktop caching my old javascript although I can't be sure. Your four bullet points above don't seem to be causing the problem but they all sound sensible so I will implement these changes. Thanks again.